# Faster Algorithm for JavaScript function call within a function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I have written a function and called another function inside but my tests show that it is not time optimized. How can I make the following code faster?

```
    function maxSum(arr, range) {


        function sumAll(array1, myrange) {

            var total = 0;

            if (Array.isArray(myrange)) {
                for (var i = myrange[0]; i <= myrange[1]; i++) {

                    total += array1[i];
                }

                return total;
            } else return array1[myrange];
        }

        var mylist = [];
        var l = range.length;


        for (var n = 0; n < l; n++) {
            mylist.push(sumAll(arr, range[n]));
        }

        return Math.max.apply(null, mylist);


    }
```

Comment: please add the call of the function as well.

Comment: I am calling the second function "sumAll" in the second forloop. Look keenly

Comment: Yes but how do you call `maxSum()`?

Comment: what data do you use for the function call?

Comment: maxSum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[[1,7],[0,2],[3,4],7]);

Comment: I am trying to get the maximum sum for each range given in the second array from the first array. That works but slower.

Comment: Your code looks reasonable. What makes you consider it "not time optimized?" How long is it taking? How long did you *expect* it to take (and why)?

Comment: There are probably faster ways to do this, at least given some assumptions about the data. (E.g. if all the numbers are non-negative, then the ranges `7` and `[3, 4]` can't possibly be the maximum, since `[1, 7]` covers both of those.)

Comment: All my tests pass but there's an error that prevents me from submitting it on codewars. I think it is the function call in another that makes it slower. Is there a way I could do that without two functions? Just one?

Comment: There are tests for negative numbers too. @smarx

Comment: If you need such micro-optimizations in your implementation to satisfy the time constraints of a coding competition, you probably haven't found the right algorithm yet.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Full working code based on @MBo's excellent optimization. This passes all the tests at https://www.codewars.com/kata/the-maximum-sum-value-of-ranges-challenge-version/train/javascript, which I gather is where this problem comes from.

```
function maxSum(arr, ranges) {
  var max = null;

  var sums = [];
  var sofar = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    sums[i] = sofar;
    sofar += arr[i];
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    var sum = sums[ranges[i][1]+1] - sums[ranges[i][0]];
    if (max === null || sum > max) {
      max = sum;
    }
  }

  return max;
}
```

Comment: I am not interested in the answer as much as I am in the working algorithm. Please explain what the code does. @smarx

Comment: It's just an implementation of the algorithm @MBo described. I'm not sure what to add to his answer.

Answer (score 3):

Algorithmic optimization: create new array with cumulative sums from index 0 to every index

```
cumsum[0] = 0;
for (var i = 1; i <= arr.Length; i++) {
  cumsum[i] = cumsum[i-1] + arr[i-1]
```

Now you don't need to calculate sums for every range - just get difference

```
 sum for range (i..j) = cumsum[j+1] - cumsum[i];
```

in your terms:

```
    function sumAll(array1, myrange) {
            return cumsum[myrange[1]+1] - cumsum[myrange[0]];
    }
```

example:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]
cumsum = [0,1,3,6,10]
sum for range 1..2 = 6 - 1 = 5
```

P.S. If your array might be updated, consider [Fenwick tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) data structure

Comment: Please explain what you are doing at  {sum for range (i..j) = cumsum[j+1] - cumsum[i];}

Comment: @Hoslack It is replacement for your function sumAll. I updated answer, tried to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can define the function `sumAll` outside of the function `maxSum` because every time you call `maxSum` the javascript engine is recreating a fresh new function `sumAll`.

2) You can define `myrange[1]` as a variable in the initialiser part to avoid javascript to look for `myrange[1]` at each iteration.

```
            for (var i = myrange[0]; i <= myrange[1]; i++) {

                total += array1[i];
            }
```

become this:

```
            for (var i = myrange[0], len = myrange[1]; i <= len; i++) {

                total += array1[i];
            }
```

Comment: I think that makes a difference but not as big enough to allow me submit it.

Comment: Removing one function would make it tremendously faster. @NBeydon

Comment: I don't really understand what the algorithm itself,  do you have some inputs and corresponding outputs?